# Porting Codebase from React to Preact-Compat, this.setState() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I'm trying to port a Codebase from React to Preact-Compat.
I basically just updated the webpack config, to alias react & react-dom with preact-compat.

```
{
  "resolve": {
  "alias": {
    "react": "preact-compat",
    "react-dom": "preact-compat"
   }
 }
}
```

But when executing the Project i get the following Error:

TypeError: this.setState is not a function

So this is obviously a react functionality which is mandatory, so that's why I'm not quite sure where to look at...

Does this ring a Bell to anyone? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this will solve your problem :

```
alias: {
  ...
  'create-react-class': 'preact-compat/lib/create-react-class'
}
```

Here you can read the whole thread upon this topic :

https://github.com/developit/preact-compat/issues/47